# TYPO3 Fluid Viewhelper Content of First Subpage

Tags: menu, typo3, fluid, viewhelper

I created a content to show the content of subpages.

```
<v:page.menu  pageUid="{page.uid}" levels="2">
         <f:for each="{menu}" as="item">
                <v:content.render pageUid="{item.uid}" column="0"/>
         </f:for>       
</v:page.menu>
```

It works!

Is there a way to get only the content of the first subpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use iterator in `<f:for>`:

```
<v:page.menu pageUid="{page.uid}" levels="2">
    <f:for each="{menu}" as="item" iteration="iterator">
        <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
            <v:content.render pageUid="{item.uid}" column="0"/>
        </f:if>
    </f:for>       
</v:page.menu>
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/For.html#example-with-iterator-information